# update null field with integer in django Python

Tags: python, mysql, django, null, integer

HI i have a field in database whose **value** is **null = true**  but i need to update it timely with the integers .I am running this script on terminal

```
getW =  get_HomeTeam_myworld.w  
getL =  get_HomeTeam_myworld.l  
if winloss == "w":
    getW = getW + 1 
    #getW.save()
    print getW
```

but it gives the following error

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

please suggest where i am doing mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like getW value is None. Add some check:

```
if winloss == "w":
    getW = getW + 1 if getW else 1
    #getW.save()
    print getW
```

Answer (score 0):

tis is right can you also please tell me how can i save this update this value in db

this is the whole process

```
get_HomeTeam_myworld = myworld.objects.get(team_id=gethome_teamID)
    get_HomeTeam_myworld = myworld.objects.get(team_id=getaway_teamID)
    getW =  get_HomeTeam_myworld.w  
    getL =  get_HomeTeam_myworld.l  
    if winloss == "w":
        getW = getW + 1 if getW else 1
        getW.save() 
        print getW
```

it gives me the following error

```
'int' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Comment: `get_HomeTeam_myworld.save()` instead of `getW.save()`

Comment: What prints `myworld.objects.get(team_id=gethome_teamID).w` after save?

Answer (score 0):

ok i fix it actuality we need to save the object

```
get_HomeTeam_myworld.(save)
```